# Are we able to Compare the Fisher Information of Two Variables?

Tags: probability, statistics

According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information), "the Fisher Information is a way of measuring the amount of information that an observable random variable X carries about an unknown parameter θ of a distribution that models X".

This being said, I thought of the following question:

- Suppose we have a variable X1 that has a Univariate Normal Distribution with parameters mu_1 and sigma_1
- Suppose we have a variable X2 that has a Univariate Normal Distribution with parameters mu_2 and sigma_2
- Suppose we have a variable X3 that has a Univariate Exponential Distribution with parameter lambda_1

I understand that it is possible to compute the Fisher Information for X1, X2 and X3 - but can we:

- **Determine if the Fisher Information of X1 is greater than the Fisher Information of X2?**
- **Determine if the Fisher Information of X3 is greater than the Fisher Information of X2?**

I am not sure if this question I have asked an appropriate use case of the Fisher Information - can someone please comment on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Fisher information is defined not for random variable, but for pair (random variable, parameter). So, are you interested in question "is information of $X_1$ about $\mu_1$ greater than information of $X_2$ about $\mu_1$" (obviously yes, the first is positive, the second is zero), or "is information of $X_1$ about $\mu_1$ greater than information of $X_2$ about $\mu_2$"?